# Is there a image-format that support an array per pixel?

Tags: raster-image, image, pixels

For a project dealing with deep semantic labeling of images I need a format that supports arrays of arbitrary length for each pixel of the image.

The array is an array of integers.

Which image formats support this?

Comment: Does the array length vary per-pixel?

Comment: How many bits are the integers? 32? 64?

Comment: array length vary per-pixel, 32 bit integers.

Answer (score 7):

OpenEXR might be a good fit. You can have an arbitrary number of channels per pixel and the data types for each channel can be integers.

http://www.openexr.com/

Answer (score 2):

Probably `.dds`. You can store there textures array or 3d texture both can be use as array per pixel.
You can try creating this textures with `DxTex` from `DirecX SDK`.
Also you can look in `Legacy Texture Tools` from Nvidia
https://developer.nvidia.com/legacy-texture-tools

Comment: Since the OP said "array of integers" without qualifying the number of bits, it perhaps seems safe to assume they mean a C-style 'int' (at least 32 bits). Does DDS support 32 bit integer channels?

Comment: Also note that since the OP did not specify that they were Windows-only, DDS may be a bit of a problem on other platforms, where few tools will properly read or write them.

Comment: According to `MSDN` DDS Format Overview:

`Note that the DDS format supports any valid DXGI_FORMAT value...`

so it support 32 bit integer.
But yes, DDS may be problem on other platforms.